# How I do check filesize of apex:inputfile when used in apex repeat

Tags: visualforce, javascript, error-messages, repeat

I have an `<apex:inputFile>` in an apex repeat. I do a check on the `<apex:inputFile>` with javascript. This seems only to be working for the first `<apex:inputFile>`. How do I manage to get this to work for the repeats.

Repeat:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!newAttachments}" var="newAtt">
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Upload file"/>                      
                    <apex:inputFile id="inputfile" value="{!newAtt.body}" filename="{!newAtt.name}"  onchange="checkFileSize(event)" />
                </apex:repeat>
```

Script:

```
<script>
        function checkFileSize(event){
            if ($("[id$=inputfile]")[0].files.length > 0) {
                //validate file attachment is not > 500k
                var uploadFileSize = $("[id$=inputfile]")[0].files[0].size;
                if (uploadFileSize > 1024 * 1024 * .5) {
                    alert('File uploads must be less than 500k in size. remove files over: '+(Math.round(uploadFileSize/1024)) + 'k');
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                else {
                    //  
                }
            }
            else {
                // no file attached, if not required, call save method
            }
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use event.target to check the correct element:

```
function checkFileSize(event) {
  if(event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    if(event.target.files[0].size > 2**19) {
      alert('File must be less than 500kb');
    } else {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

There's no need to use jQuery here.

Comment: Could you please explain the 2**19 part?

Comment: It's 2 to the 19th power, which is the same as `1024 * 1024 * .5` but with a lot less typing.